# Upload video to youtube using internal as user type in consent screen

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I tried to upload a video to YouTube using **YouTube data api v3**, when i select external(in consent screen) as a type it works fine, however it doesn't work when i set the type to internal(i created an organization using Google Workspace), i got this **org_internal** error.

I want to know if there is something wrong when i choose internal?
or this error is related to YouTube?
or something wrong with project configuration?

Comment: The project needs to be created by your workspace domain account to be able to set it internal.   TBH im not even sure if you can set YouTube internal

Comment: I created the project using my workspace domain account the problem is when i select youtube channel to get access and refresh tokens it said: "org_internal".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: there is the code
 ```js
  const service = google.youtube('v3');
    const res = await service.videos.insert({
      auth: auth,
      part: 'snippet,status',
      requestBody: {
        snippet: {title,description,categoryId: categoryIds.Entertainment,},
        status: {privacyStatus: "private"},
      },
      media: {
        body: fs.createReadStream(pathTovideo),
      },
    });```